# Listen custom Button click and re-render dates in controller for angularJs datePicker popup

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have overridden datepicker popup to add a custom button.
My custom button is wrapped inside `<script id="template/datepicker/popup.html" type="text/ng-template">`
directive.

I can see the custom button like the picture below but I want to listen the click of "Regular Price" button in my controller and re-render all the dates of calendar with some new custom css. I was unable to get any event in my controller using `ng-click` for the custom button.

[image]

How can I achieve it in my controller ?

### Edit

Html

```
<!-- Overriding code for popup calendar-->
<script id="template/datepicker/popup.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ul class="uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu" dropdown-nested ng-if="isOpen" style="display: block" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">

  <!-- regular price button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" ng-click="regularPrice()">Regular Price</button>
  <!-- /regular price button-->

  <li ng-transclude></li>
  <li ng-if="showButtonBar" style="padding:10px 9px 2px" class="uib-button-bar">
    <span class="btn-group pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today')" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger uib-clear" ng-click="select(null)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close()">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
</script>
<!-- /Overriding code for popup calendar -->

<div class="text-center">Check-in</div>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="check_in_date" is-open="checkInOpened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"  ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-change="selectedCheckinDate(check_in_date)" min-date="{{minDate}}" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)" show-weeks="false" disabled="disabled" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCheckIn($event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

In controller

```
$scope.regularPrice = function(){
  alert('regular selected');
};
```

Comment: How come ng-click cant work here ? Can you provide the code you have tried ?

Comment: post your js and html code

Comment: I have included my html and js in the edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `uibDatepickerPopup` directive creates an *isolated* scope and `ng-include` creates a child scope,  `regularPrice` handler defined in your controller could be accessed like this: `$parent.$parent.regularPrice()`

Here is a *modified* popup template:

```
<div>
<ul class="uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu" dropdown-nested ng-if="isOpen" style="display: block" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
  <!-- regular price button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" ng-click="$parent.$parent.regularPrice()">Regular Price</button>
  <!-- /regular price button-->

  <li ng-transclude></li>
  <li ng-if="showButtonBar" style="padding:10px 9px 2px" class="uib-button-bar">
    <span class="btn-group pull-left">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today')" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger uib-clear" ng-click="select(null)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close($event)">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/azYXhNU6b1jym9hYZu9X?p=preview)

Comment: is it possible to re-render dates when I press regular button inside popup window?